# Does exists ability to specify view animation in xml?

Tags: android, xml, animation

I know that exists ability to specify drawable animation `<animation-list>` in xml, like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/my_list_animation"
         />
```

But i not found any mention about ability to specify view animation `<set>` in xml. 
Besides when i tried to specify it in xml:

```
android:src="@anim/fadein"
```

i got an exception:

> Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag set

Does exists ability to specify view animation in xml without custom attributes?

Comment: I think by default the only way to use an animation is from java code, not possible from xml layout.

Comment: some simple animations can be done using transitions for API level > 12 I think.

Comment: `android:src` accept a drawable, `<set>` is an `AnimationSet`, `<animation-list>` is an `AnimationDrawable`, in java code

Answer (score 0):

**[Wrong]**  crash!!!: invalid drawable tag set

```
        <Button android:background="@drawable/bg_zselector"  android:text="Selector"/>
```

**[Right]**

```
        <Button android:stateListAnimator="@drawable/bg_zselector"  android:text="Selector"/>
```

Note: StateListAnimator is added since API level 21